# Concurrency issue with new Bitmap(oldBitmapInstance)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, gdi+

The following two snippets are used concurrently by multiple threads:

```
Bitmap newBitmap = null;
lock (currentBitmap)
    newBitmap = new Bitmap(currentBitmap); // throws InvalidOperationException
```

The newBitmap object is manipulated in the meantime by using Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap) and subsequently some drawing methods of the Graphics object.

```
lock (currentBitmap)
    currentBitmap= new Bitmap(newBitmap);
```

Those are **the only** interactions with the currentBitmap object. I am **never** handing over it's reference like

```
Bitmap xxx = currentBitmap;
```

Yet on the first snippet at the Bitmap constructor it throws an InvalidOperationException. In my opinion this shouldn't be able to happen because of the lock statements. Aren't they ensuring that it's never used by two threads at once unless the reference "escapes" somehow, which it doesn't in my case?
What more do I need to do besides locking the object?

Comment: You shouldn't use for `lock` the object itself. Make for it a dedicated `object currentBitmapLock = new object();`

Comment: Post that as answer and I gonna accept it, because that's exactly my problem. The funny thing is I got the solution just a few seconds ago by reading the Related "What is the most frequent concurrency issue you've encountered in Java?" thread :P

Comment: Looks like you're locking on different objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that when each time the lock statement is executed it will evaluate the current reference pointed to by the parameter you pass to it.  In this case as you are overwriting the variable that is passed to lock so each time it is executed it will lock on a different reference.

You should never lock on an object that is modified within the lock statement.  Also, you should never lock on a value type (as there is no global reference) nor lock on `this` (as you don't control which other classes can have a reference to yours and lock on it).

As a guideline you should look to lock on a dedicated object created for this purpose and in my opinion this object should also be defined as `readonly`.

```
private readonly _shared = new object();

private void SomeMethod()
{    
    lock (_shared) 
    {
         // Stuff
    }
}
```